# How to show App icon in ACTION_SEND intent - android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want the app icon to be shown when sharing my app inside my app. When clicking the Share the App button in my App. It works but instead of my icon, it shows some other icon.
It shows like Below

[image]

Here's the code I used:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " Knowledge");
String shareMessage= "\n Download now for free !\n\n";
shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"\n\n";
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
```

How can I set my icon in here? Please help me with some solution

Comment: Hello @fohibi, did you get code for showing app icon in share dialog top bar.

Comment: HI @fohibi , if you get the solution please let me know , actually i am waiting for this

Comment: @fohibi, Did you get a solution. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations guys, you waited for this :)

In some cases you need to add several Intent filters:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.FeedActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        
        <intent-filter>
            
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        
        </intent-filter>
        
        <intent-filter>
            
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            
        </intent-filter>
        
        <intent-filter>
            
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            
        </intent-filter>
        
        <intent-filter>
            
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            
        </intent-filter>
        
    </activity>
```

And be sure you add the `android:exported="true"` tag otherwise you app won't appear in other share intents.